# How do I upgrade SQL Report projects (rptproj) to Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: reporting, visual-studio-2012, bids

Were I work we are currently using visual studio 2008 because 2010 did not include the bids stuff, I have now been asked to test out whether 2012 is any better so we have a virtual machine that I've been allowed to work on and we've got visual studio 2012 and 2012 integration services installed on it.

I tried to open one of our solutions which has various report projects in it. When I do this I get a one way upgrade option which I chose and then I get the following:

> Projectname.rptproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=11&sbp=ProjectTypeDeprecated&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=ProjectCompatibility&o1=F14B399A-7131-4C87-9E4B-1186C45EF12D)

This link doesn't work properly and I can't seem to find very much on this for visual studio 2012 am I missing something here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 19):

Microsoft has recently released [the tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) necessary to open and create .rptproj projects in VS2012: [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843)

Comment: Beware, if you have x64 installed, make sure to select **Perform a new installation of SQL Server 2012**, [props go to this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jenss/archive/2013/03/07/finally-the-family-united-sql-server-bi-project-templates-now-available-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh322942), it appears that you have to install the client tools for VS2012 (from the SQL2012 installer) in order to get the BIDS bits. Incidentally, installing VS2012 client tools will apparently update both VS2010 and VS2012.

Comment: Sorry, just tried this for myself; it appears that SQL BI projects are not yet supported in VS2012 (sound familiar from SQL2008/VS2010?). According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/f800376f-c782-4500-8423-22fb1374cae4, it should be available by the end of the year (I for one will not be holding my breath though).

Comment: How about editing your original answer to include the info in the comment? :-)